# Elasticbeanstalk - Apache and htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to get a WordPress site working on Elasticbeanstalk using apache. When i run it using nginx, everything works fine, but with apache, i get the following error:

```
var/www/html/.htaccess: <IfModule not allowed here, referer: http://www.example.com/
```

Do I need to add any more configuration in elasticbeanstalk or perhaps alter the httpd.conf to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Did you already add "AllowOverride All" in your vhost or httpd.conf for the directory /var/www/html? Like this: <Directory /var/www/> Options Indexes FollowSymLinks AllowOverride None Require all granted </Directory>

Comment: @LukasRäpple there isn't a vhost defined in the httpd.conf or a <Directory> directive

Comment: Ok, odd.In my apache 2.4 installations there is always the folowwing inside https.conf: <Directory />
    Options None
    AllowOverride None
    <IfModule !mod_access_compat.c>
        Require all denied
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_access_compat.c>
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
    </IfModule>
</Directory>

Comment: @LukasRäpple is this via elasticbeanstalk? I'm using Amazon Linux, if that helps?

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same error and resolved it by manually updating the /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf file by adding the following content:

```
<Directory "/var/www">
    AllowOverride ALL
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

And then restarted the apache service by running the following command:

```
sudo systemctl restart httpd
```